# Laravel Twitter Library - Where is the static function getUserTimeline()

Tags: php, oop, laravel, twitter

I'm new in Laravel, I'm trying to understand how it works. I have setup this library as defined.

https://github.com/thujohn/twitter-l4

Examples works perfect when I define use with only Twitter; Shown below

```
    use Stream;
    use Twitter;

    class GoController extends \BaseController{
        function go($id){
             return Twitter::getUserTimeline(array('screen_name' => 'thujohn', 'count' => 20, 'format' => 'json'));
        }
}
```

but it throws this error when I use Thujohn\Twitter\Twitter;

```
    use Stream;
    use Thujohn\Twitter\Twitter;

    class GoController extends \BaseController{
        function go($id){
             return Twitter::getUserTimeline(array('screen_name' => 'thujohn', 'count' => 20, 'format' => 'json'));
        }
}
```

> Non-static method Thujohn\Twitter\Twitter::getUserTimeline() should
>   not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context

So, I'm unable to understand why I can't use the second form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beacuse in the second example you're using the class directly, which happens to have the same name as the alias accessor.

What you see called statically is a *Façade*, which actually instantiates the class by using a static method (I'm not really good at explaining things...)

If you followed the instructions you should have created an Alias in the `config/app.php` file.

```
'Twitter' => 'Thujohn\Twitter\TwitterFacade',
```

And this alias is the very `Twitter` class (i.e., the façade) you need to call, and that you see called in the documentation.

So, remove the `use` statement `use Thujohn\Twitter\Twitter;` and your code will be using the "Twitter" alias (like it did in the first example), i.e. will call the Facade accessor.

```
 use Stream;

 class GoController extends \BaseController
 {

    public function go($id)
    {
      return \Twitter::getUserTimeline(array('screen_name' => 'thujohn', 'count' => 20, 'format' => 'json'));
    }
 }
```

Comment: Can you please show me an example how to load an unstatic class as static?